# Boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, emr, amazon-emr

I'm trying to run a (py)Spark job on EMR that will process a large amount of data. Currently my job is failing with the following error message:

```
Reason: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits.
5.5 GB of 5.5 GB physical memory used.
Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.
```

So I google'd how to do this, and found that I should pass along the `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead` parameter with the --conf flag. I'm doing it this way:

```
aws emr add-steps\
--cluster-id %s\
--profile EMR\
--region us-west-2\
--steps Name=Spark,Jar=command-runner.jar,\
Args=[\
/usr/lib/spark/bin/spark-submit,\
--deploy-mode,client,\
/home/hadoop/%s,\
--executor-memory,100g,\
--num-executors,3,\
--total-executor-cores,1,\
--conf,'spark.python.worker.memory=1200m',\
--conf,'spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=15300',\
],ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE" % (cluster_id,script_name)\
```

But when I rerun the job it keeps giving me the same error message, with the `5.5 GB of 5.5 GB physical memory used`, which implies that my memory did not increase.. any hints on what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Here are details on how I initially create the cluster:

```
aws emr create-cluster\
--name "Spark"\
--release-label emr-4.7.0\
--applications Name=Spark\
--bootstrap-action Path=s3://emr-code-matgreen/bootstraps/install_python_modules.sh\
--ec2-attributes KeyName=EMR2,InstanceProfile=EMR_EC2_DefaultRole\
--log-uri s3://emr-logs-zerex\
--instance-type r3.xlarge\
--instance-count 4\
--profile EMR\
--service-role EMR_DefaultRole\
--region us-west-2'
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check the logs of the job ?

Comment: Yes @Koffee, that is where I got the error message from. It is failing when it tries to execute a SparkSQL statement that groups the data by a number of variables and then aggregates it (i.e. "select name, min(number) from table group by name"). I copied a more detailed section of the log here: http://pastebin.com/KVrbDkHu

Comment: Which instance do you use ? m3.xlarge ? I think `--total-executor-cores` argument could only be used by Spark in standalone mode and not over Yarn.

Comment: @Koffee I'm using 4 instances of r3.xlarge. Do you have any suggestions of which Args=[] to pass to add-steps to increase `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead`? I tried removing `--total-executor-cores` but the output is the same....

Comment: Maybe you could try to reduce the --executor-memory, this option corresponds to the amount of memory to use per executor process. r3.xlarge contains only 30,5g so you cannot have 100g per executor.

Comment: @Koffee still the same result.. I've added the create-config details I am using, could you please take a look and let me know if you got any other suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After a couple of hours I found the solution to this problem. When creating the cluster, I needed to pass on the following flag as a parameter:

```
--configurations file://./sparkConfig.json\
```

With the JSON file containing:

```
[
    {
      "Classification": "spark-defaults",
      "Properties": {
        "spark.executor.memory": "10G"
      }
    }
  ]
```

This allows me to increase the memoryOverhead in the next step by using the parameter I initially posted.

Answer (score 10):

If you are logged into an EMR node and want to further alter Spark's default settings without dealing with the AWSCLI tools you can add a line to the `spark-defaults.conf` file. Spark is located in EMR's /etc directory. Users can access the file directly by navigating to or editing `/etc/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf`

So in this case we'd append `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead` to the end of the spark-defaults file. The end of the file looks very similar to this example:

```
spark.driver.memory              1024M
spark.executor.memory            4305M
spark.default.parallelism        8
spark.logConf                    true
spark.executorEnv.PYTHONPATH     /usr/lib/spark/python
spark.driver.maxResultSize       0
spark.worker.timeout             600
spark.storage.blockManagerSlaveTimeoutMs 600000
spark.executorEnv.PYTHONHASHSEED 0
spark.akka.timeout               600
spark.sql.shuffle.partitions     300
spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead 1000M
```

Similarly, the heap size can be controlled with the `--executor-memory=xg` flag or the `spark.executor.memory property`.

Hope this helps...

Comment: fwiw when I set spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead using a format like "1000M" I get a `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1000M"`.  spark documentation says this is "The amount of off-heap memory (in megabytes)"...  so I leave off the 'M' and just set it as "1000" and it seems to work.